# How to run a groovy file which include other groovy files please?

Tags: groovy

I have three groovy file: /my.groovy, /my_dir/util.groovy, /my_dir/base.groovy

my.groovy:

```
def shell = new GroovyShell()
def util = shell.parse(new File("my_dir/util.groovy"))
println(util.run());
```

util.groovy:

```
def getName(String name) {
    def base = new base();
    return name * base.getTimes();
}

println(getName('hi,'));
```

base.groovy:

```
def getTimes() {
    return 20;
}
```

Now I run groovy my.groovy, and it can not work because unable to resolve class base. If these files all in the same dir, it can work. How to do it in this case please? (with no compile)

Answer (score 0):

A.groovy

```
def b=new B()
println b.greet("world")
```

./mydir/B.groovy

```
def greet(n){
    return "hello $n"
}
```

assume you are in the directory where A.groovy located

how to run:

```
groovy -cp ./mydir/ A.groovy
```

in this case you are running class `A` and specifying to lookup other classes from directory `./mydir/`

---

**or you can use packages:**

A.groovy

```
import mydir.*

def b=new B()
println b.greet("world")
```

./mydir/B.groovy

```
package mydir

def greet(n){
    return "hello $n"
}
```

how to run:

```
groovy -cp . A.groovy
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it, I can use getClass() and get path in util.groovy to find the base.groovy. but I do not think it is an elegant solution. I means like python, just import file and can use the methods in that file. Could groovy do it?